# without displaying "(base)" after installing anaconda

Tags: 22.04, anaconda

I was trying to install anaconda in ubuntu 22.04.4.

`sudo ./name_of_anaconda.sh`was executed but after installing, I couldn't find "base" at the begin of the command line. However, when I tried to use `bash ./name_of_anaconda.sh`, the problem was solved.
Although the problem was solved, I still wonder why the problem occurred.

Comment: Related: [Why does "(base)" appear in front of my terminal prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026383/why-does-base-appear-in-front-of-my-terminal-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

`(base)` is displayed because the "base" environment has been activated.  Some people like that (to have the base environment always activated).  Others would rather explicitly activate an environment (including the base environment) by using the `conda activate ...` command.

If you want to activate it by default, then you don't need to do anything for the root user.

If you want to have it deactivated, then create a file `~/.condarc` and in that file, put this value:

```
auto_activate_base: false
```

Of course, if you want to explicitly activate it, you can also put the value "true" here.